# How to change style of a node based on its name?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I've create pie charts using pgf-pie and I have exactly the same problem as in this [pgf-pie issue](http://code.google.com/p/pgf-pie/issues/detail?id=1).

I changed pgf-pie code to draw small percentages outside of the main circle. But I have one problem that remains: if the numbers are very very small the values are written on top of each other:[image]

IMHO this can only be fixed on the chart itselft. I added names to all nodes that print percent values. I want to change style or position of these nodes. Is there any way to do this?

changed pgf-pie code at line 58.

```
%\path (O) -- ++(\midangle:\innerpos) 
%node {\scalefont{#3}\beforenumber\fnum\afternumber};

\pgfmathprintnumberto{#3}{\fnum} 

\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{#3 pt < 10pt}}
{
\path (O) -- ++ (\midangle:\radius)
node[inner sep=0,align=left,anchor=west,rotate=\midangle](nums#3){~~\fnum};
}
{    
\path (O) -- ++(\midangle:\innerpos) 
node {\scalefont{#3}\beforenumber\fnum\afternumber};
}
```

diagram:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every legend entry/.append style={text width=5cm,font=\footnotesize},scale=0.95]
\pie[
    sum=auto,
    text=legend, 
    rotate =90,
    radius=5.0,
    after number=\%,
    ]   
    {
    0.444/message transport other,
    67.792/sign,
    0.175/forwarding,
    0.433/links send other ,
    1.093/serialize message,
    2.336/send message,
    2.336/link receive ,
    2.232/forwarding receive ,
    10.770/parse signature block,
    11.818/verify signature,
    0.570/parse message content}

    %\draw (0,0) node[outer sep=0pt,fill=blue,below of=nums0.433,anchor=west] {filled};\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That looks like an answer to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really recommend the `pgf-pie` package due to its inflexibility (and its use of the main PGFkeys path) but since you are already changing its original code, you can add a special style to your node:

```
\path (O) -- ++ (\midangle:\radius) node[
  inner sep=0, align=left, anchor=west, rotate=\midangle,
  special style={\midangle}{#3}] (nums#3) {\beforenumber\fnum\afternumber};
```

If you set up `special style` correctly so that it checks (its own) `#2` it can apply another shift like `shift=(#1:1cm)` (which of course can be set with other styles and/or values.

I doubt `#3` is the best parameter you can use since it will have the decimal point from your values in it (which—if you want to refer to such a node—will be understood as a divider between a node's name and its anchor). You might just want to use `\i` here (for both the name and the special style) which `pgf-pie` actually uses as a counter-macro for the loop (see the definition of `\pie` on line 407ff.) but does not forward to `\pgfpie@slice`.

Answer (score 0):

The [wheelchart](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

A command `\WCtest` is defined of which the output depends on whether the percentage is larger than 3. This command is used in the keys `data` and `wheel data`. Here, the percentage is obtained with `\WCperc`.

The angle of the point where the data is placed is shifted with the key `data angle shift`.

The legend is determined by the key `legend`. This is a `tabular` which is placed in a `\node`. The rows are determined by the key `legend row`. The result of all rows can be obtained with `\WClegend`.

In the key `slices style` we use `\WClistcolors` which refers to items in the list given to the key `WClistcolors`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\WCtest#1#2{%
    \pgfmathparse{\WCpercentage>3?"#1":"#2"}%
    \pgfmathresult%
}
\wheelchart[
  counterclockwise,
  data=\WCtest{}{\WCperc},
  data angle shift=\WCvarB,
  data style={rotate=\WCmidangle,anchor=west},
  legend row={\tikz\fill[\WClistcolors,draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (0.3,0.3); & \WCvarC},
  legend={
    \node[anchor=west] at (6,3.5) {%
      \begin{tabular}{l@{ }l}%
      \WClegend%
      \end{tabular}%
    };
  },
  perc precision=2,
  radius={0}{5},
  slices style={\WClistcolors,draw=black},
  WClistcolors={blue!60,cyan!60,yellow!60,orange!60,red!60,blue!60!cyan!60,cyan!60!yellow!60,red!60!cyan!60,red!60!blue!60,orange!60!cyan!60,blue!60},
  wheel data=\WCtest{\WCperc}{}
]{%
  0.444/1/message transport other,
  67.792/0/sign,
  0.175/-3/forwarding,
  0.433/0/links send other,
  1.093/1/serialize message,
  2.336/0/send message,
  2.336/0/link receive,
  2.232/0/forwarding receive,
  10.770/0/parse signature block,
  11.818/0/verify signature,
  0.570/-1/parse message content%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```